# Did the CNN reporter mispronounce the word 'wary'?

Tags: pronunciation, portmanteau-words

In this [CNN report](https://youtu.be/L8NqJxU2qK8?t=35s), a CNN reporter said this:

> ...
>
> Xi complied and as they were in the process of returning, you might recall, the president tweeted out wondering aloud if they would thank him for his role in their return. All three of them did and president tweeted at them saying, he was glad that they were home, that they should be **wary** of many pitfalls in life.
>
> ...

The word 'wary' starts at 35 seconds of the video.

Firsts things first. I understand that some **writers** misuse the word 'weary' when they should use 'wary' instead.

Now, the question is, did the CNN reporter really mispronounce the word 'wary' or can that be a correct pronunciation of the word 'wary'?

Simply by the pronunciation of the word, it sounds to me like 'weary'. But contexts dictates that it be 'wary'.

### EDIT

Regarding the context dictating that the word should be 'wary', here's what Trump tweeted (according to [this Politico article](https://www.politico.com/story/2017/11/16/trump-ucla-players-advice-244972)):

> "Be careful, there are many pitfalls on the long and winding road of life!"

### EDIT

This question is closed based on the erroneous claim that the mispronunciation of "wary" as "weary" is merely an isolated mistake on the part of the CNN reporter himself.

The same mistakes of using "weary" instead of "wary", however, have been noticed even in writing.

Here's what Garner's Modern American Usage says on page 851.

Specifically, see the third paragraph and the following three examples.

[image]
[image]

Now, if native speakers can easily misuse "weary" even in writing  when they mean "wary", no wonder native speakers will easily misuse "weary" in speaking when they mean "wary". Therefore, I seriously doubt that the CNN reporter's misuse of the word is a one-off mistake.

Comment: Why can't they be just tired of said pitfalls.

Comment: Maybe he just mis-read it from his script or the auto-cue?

Comment: "wary" and "weary" aren't even close.  I'd say the text was supposed to be "wary" and there's a typo on the teleprompter.

Comment: @Xanne Perhaps a Freudian slip on the part of the President. He must indeed be "weary" of his own many pitfalls!  But had he been "wary" he would not now be "weary". There would seem to be profound irony in  President Trump counselling anyone to be "wary of pitfalls in life".

Comment: @Xanne So are you saying that the CNN reporter's pronunciation of the word can't be correct as that of 'wary'?

Comment: @Jk2 That's what I think.  He seems quite standard and precise in his diction.  But of course it's possible.  He's reading a teleprompter.  What he thought he was reading was "weary," not "wary."  Why does it matter?  It makes sense to by wary of pitfalls, not to be weary of pitfalls.

Comment: This isn't a question about the English language, it's a question about one man's mispronunciation. We've all mispronounced words by accident, some presenters will auto-correct themselves, and some TV reporters will pretend nothing has happened, hoping no one will have noticed, and carry on doing their job.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What job?

Comment: @Ricky telling the news?

Comment: @Mari-LouA We're in the middle of unprecedented energy, political, and financial crises, and have been since at least 2008. I don't remember any newspeople "telling" this news on any of the major networks. But what do I know? I'm merely a Puccini fan.

Comment: I’ve heard this mispronounciation often enough in my day to day native speaking life to have taken note of it. My speculation has been and continues to be that people are mixing *wary* with the semantically similar *leery*, producing *weary*, which their minds don’t correct and filter, because they’ve definitely heard that word produced as well.

Comment: @DanBron That's in accordance to Garner's explanation. This actually reminds me of the misuse of "lay" instead of "lie" by native speakers, as in "You gotta lay low" instead of "You gotta lie low".